Win driver sample ,simple audio sample
I read the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-driver-samples/simple-audio-sample-device-driver/
The Microsoft Simple Audio Sample Device Driver shows how to develop a simple WDM audio driver that exposes support for two basic audio devices (a speaker and microphone array). These audio devices are embedded in the system (not pluggable) and the driver uses WaveRT for rendering these devices. The driver also uses a "virtual audio device" instead of an actual hardware-based adapter.
I try to build a audio driver,
I use vs2022 community and build the source code pass.
But When I use devcon to install the driver ,it tells me devcon fail.
could you give me a hand?
mount the driver on my system

are you signing the result? the linked document mentions signing as being important

yes I signing the result

copy the Devcon and past it inside the package folder and then run "devcon install SimpleAudioSample.inf Root\SimpleAudioSample" in CMD administrator, also ensure to disable all the firewall protection and disable the digital signature requirement.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
